# Cosa significa "cassetta" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il giorno della civetta*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> «Non sta soffrendo niente, se tu pensi che lo tengano legato alla **cassetta** o gli 
>   diano le scosse elettriche: altri tempi, quelli delle **cassette**; ore c'è la legge anche per i carabinieri...».

Ho cercato il vocabolo "cassetta" in parecchi dizionari. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire cosa significa nel passaggio precedente. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: http://www.corriere.it/Primo_Piano/Esteri/2004/05_Maggio/05/dossier.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La **cassetta** non era altro che una forma di tortura praticata (purtroppo anche) dalle forze dell’ordine.

Ecco un estratto da [Le torture della polizia negli anni di piombo](http://www.ilpost.it/2012/02/16/sofri-de-tormentis/)

> A volte la cosa “scappava di mano”, come nella questura di Palermo,
>   1985. Oscar Luigi Scalfaro, che era allora ministro dell´Interno, dichiarò: “Un cittadino è entrato vivo in una stanza di polizia e ne è
>   uscito morto”. Era un giovane mafioso, fu picchiato e torturato col
>   metodo della “**cassetta**”: un tubo spinto in gola e riempito di acqua
>   salata. Gli sfondò la trachea, il cadavere fu portato su una spiaggia
>   per simularne l´annegamento in mare. Alla notte di tortura
>   parteciparono o assistettero decine di agenti e funzionari. Avevano
>   molte attenuanti: era stato appena assassinato un valoroso funzionario
>   di polizia, Beppe Montana, “Serpico”.

Ci sono anche [questi documenti](http://www.nuovaalabarda.org/leggi-articolo-giornata_della_memoria_2009%3A_metodi_repressivi_dell'ispettorato_speciale_di_ps..php) risalenti al primissimo dopoguerra segnalati da @Charo in cui viene descritta in modo ancora più preciso:

> L’ispettore Umberto De Giorgi della Polizia Scientifica firmò in data
>   18/1/46 una *perizia sui metodi di tortura dell’Ispettorato Speciale*.
>   Tale perizia, richiesta dal Procuratore Generale Colonna per conto
>   della Corte d’Assise Straordinaria di Trieste (copia in archivio
>   IRSMLT 913) descrive, tra le altre cose, i metodi di tortura della
>   “**cassetta**” e della “sedia elettrica”. Leggiamone le descrizioni: 
>   stando alle deposizioni testimoniali, allorquando la vittima non
>   confessava (nonostante il dolore provocato dalla distensione forzata
>   di tutto il corpo mediante trazione delle corde fissate agli arti e
>   fatte scorrere negli anelli infissi al pavimento, che spesso
>   provocavano la lussazione delle spalle), era costretta a subire
>   l’introduzione nell’esofago del tubo dell’acqua, che le veniva fatta
>   ingoiare fino a riempimento totale dello stomaco; indi per azione di
>   compressione esercitata da un segugio sul torace, le veniva fatta
>   rigurgitare a mo’ di fontana, che, stante la posizione supina, spesso
>   doveva minacciare di soffocamento la vittima stessa;

Comment: Se ne parla anche [qui](http://www.nuovaalabarda.org/leggi-articolo-giornata_della_memoria_2009%3A_metodi_repressivi_dell'ispettorato_speciale_di_ps..php).

Comment: Se vuoi, puoi includere la informazione che appare nel link del mio commento precedente nella tua risposta. Penso che così la risposta possa diventare più completa. Penso sia interessante perché è una descrizione di questo metodo di tortura proveniente da un documento firmato da un ispettore di polizia nel 1946.

Comment: @Charo Fatto. Grazie

Comment: Grazie, @abarisone!